# Задачник и решебник по темам JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Не подскажите ресурс/книгу, где было бы много задач (с ответами) по чистому JS ?

Например тема "переменные в JS" и в конце темы огромный перечень задач по теме "переменные". Возможно даже без учебного материала по теме, но  с задачами/ответами по определенной теме (задачи простые и среднесложные).

Как пример ресурс learn.javascript (но вот беда, мало задач под каждой темой!)
(Ресурсы типа codewars, где всё вперемешку не рассматриваю)

Comment: Поясню зачем по  темам  и с большим перечнем несложных задач ... Вычитал,  что навык решения задач тренировать надо изолированно на простых задачах. Так материал закрепляется  и не отпугивается .. Поэтому и отсекаю ресурсы типа codewars

Comment: [tag:javascript]

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/  https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/

Comment: @VenomJS зря вы не рассматриваете CW. Для того чтобы решать только необходимые для себя задачи, вы можете использовать поиск по тегам или зайти в коллекции. Тогда вы увидите задачи, рассортированные по темам.

Comment: нет нет, ни в коем случае  CW не отметаю. На этом ресурсе тоже практикуюсь. Просто хочу  найти кучу изолированных "под темы" задач..

Comment: Но ведь learn.javascript отличный ресурс! Да, его задачи лишь для ознакомления, но с таким ресурсом Вам и вправду стоит самому ставить себе задачи. Лично я использовал этот же источник для изучения JS. Теперь, когда уже работаю, использую его как справочник. И всем доволен!

Answer (score -2):

Я рекомендую вам не тратить своё время на бесцельное изучение теории, обучение гораздо проще проходит, и усваивается информация, когда вы решаете какую то конкретную задачу, и ищете инфу о том, каким образом она решается. Создавайте сайты, придумывайте функционал который хотите реализовать, и пишите его, попутно узнавая как это делается. Только так вы научитесь именно программировать, и использовать свои знания в деле.

Comment: Ну, вы не совсем правы. В процессе разработки возникает немало вопросов. Предварительно прочтеная документация поможет с гуглением, представлением лучшего решения и т.п.. Да, практика важна, но читать, когда уже встрял по самое немогу - это не то. По себе знаю